# How to delete data in tempDirectory on app restart/shutdown - Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: android, ios, titanium, appcelerator

Part of my app functionalities is allowing user to multi select photos from gallery and then upload them. Before uploading, user is free to add/delete their photos.

What I'm doing is I create and store these temporary image files in Titanium.Filesystem.tempDirectory, with an intention that these will be deleted eventually on app restart or shutdown.

Though, when I use Finder to track these files, they're still there and do not get deleted after I close and reopen the app/reboot ios simulator. 
So do I have to explicitly delete these files? Does the actual ios device behave any differently?

Thank you

Simply the codes where these img files get created:

```
var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.tempDirectory, fileName);
if (f.write(imageBlob) === false) {
    console.log("Image writing failed");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just leave the files there. On a device they will be cleaned up when the device needs space.